# GSP Template fails to retrieve passed template from another template

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I'm working on a Grails 2.4.4 project. I have the following code on my `gsp` page (**not** a template) that calls a sub template that calls another template: `main gsp page > gsp template > yet another gsp template`:

**main.gsp**

```
...
<g:render template="/details" model="[param_one:'param_one', param_two:'param_two']" />
...
```

**_details.gsp**

```
...
<p>On details: ${param_one}</p>
<g:render template="/segments/segment-one" model="[param_two:'${param_two}']" />
...
```

**_segment-one.gsp**

```
<p>Segment One: ${param_two}</p>
```

Now when it renders the whole page, it only shows something like this:

```
On details: param_one
Segment One: ${param_two}
```

Why does `_segment-one.gsp` fails to render the passed `param_two`? Is it not allowed to have `template` from another `template` rendering? Thanks guys.

Comment: what happens if you pass `model="[param_two: param_two]"` ?

Comment: It tells me that there are `unescaped` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code in `_segment-one.gsp` by adding the `params` keyword:

```
<p>Segment One: ${params.param_two}</p>
                  ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are allowed to have gsp pages call templates that call templates indefinitely. When you call a template, you are literally including the code of the template into the including page at runtime; in other words, a template is part of the caller and it would have access by default to all objects visible to the caller. All you have to do is to change your second inclusion to:

```
<g:render template="/segments/segment-one" />
```

Now, template segment-one will already have access to param_one and param_two. You only need to use your *model* tag again if you are passing something new created in the local template (or gsp) you are in.

Comment: `${param_two}` doesn't work, so I tried using `${params.param_two}`, then it now works. I'll try your solution if it works also.

Comment: Of course you had to deal with that typo of yours first :-). What I suggested works I just tried it.